# SQL: Foreign Key not Referencing Correctly

Tags: sql, reference, foreign-keys

I have the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Doctor 
(
    ssn CHAR(11) PRIMARY KEY,
    name CHAR(30),
    specialty CHAR(30),
    yearsOfExperience INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Pri_Phy_Patient  
(
    ssn CHAR(11) PRIMARY KEY,
    name CHAR(20),
    age INTEGER,
    address CHAR(200),
    phy_ssn CHAR(11),
    FOREIGN KEY (phy_ssn) REFERENCES Doctor(ssn)
);
```

`select * from doctor` returns the following:

```
ssn     name        specialty   yearsOfExperience
-------------------------------------------------
156188  Dr. Doctor  Doctorism   12
338738  Dr. Jim     Eyes        2
4354354 Dr. Man     Legs        1
453543  Dr. Woman   Arms        5
```

`select * from pri_phy_patient` returns this:

```
ssn     name    age address                           phy_ssn
-------------------------------------------------------------
1234134 Patrick 32  331 Patrickson Lane, Patton, CO   NULL
1234597 Patty   23  331 Patterson Dr, Pattington, IL  NULL
654643  Pamela  46  331 Pammerson Rd, Pammington, OR  NULL
```

Why is the `phy_ssn` column returning as `NULL` for `Pri_Phy_Patient`? I'm referencing `phy_ssn` with `Doctor(ssn)`. Shouldn't the `phy_ssn` column have all the doctor SSNs?

Comment: phy_ssn is nullable, meaning that you can have a row in Pri_Phy_Patient with no corresponding row in Doctor.  If that's not what you want, make phy_ssn NOT NULL.

Comment: When I make `phy_ssn` `NOT NULL`, I get the error: ``Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`project`.`pri_phy_patient`, CONSTRAINT `pri_phy_patient_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`phy_ssn`) REFERENCES `doctor` (`ssn`))``

Comment: Well, how are you **inserting** data into the patient table?? Are you providing a valid value for the `phy_ssn` when inserting??

Answer (score 0):

I think the term "Foreign Key" isn't very clear for you.

Let me try explaining it. A foreign key is a field that references a primary key in another table.

Let's check this example:

- Table 1: Book (Id, Title, AuthorId)
- Table 2: Authors (AuthorId, Name, Gender)

In this scenario, the column `AuthorId` in the table `Book` references the column `AuthorId` in the table `Authors`.

Now let's go back to your case. The column `phy_ssn` in the table `pri_phy_patient` yes references the column `ssn` in the table doctor, but it is nullable, so it can be Null. It shouldn't contain all the doctor ssns.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Okay. Do you know how I can "connect" `doctor(ssn)` to `pri_phy_patient(phy_ssn)`? I tried making `phy_ssn` `NOT NULL`, but that just threw an error.

Comment: Maybe it is throwing an error because there are already Null Values for the field phy_ssn. Try updating the field values to Not Null values, and then make the field phy_ssn Not Null.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this. I already drop all the tables I made previously when I run the sql script, so each table is a fresh table whenever I run the sql script. Shouldn't putting `NOT NULL,` after `phy_ssn CHAR(11)` do what you're suggesting to do?

Comment: Try adding Not Null to Primary Keys also!

Comment: I want to make it clear. Adding the not null to foreign keys, will only forbid you from adding a row to the table pri_phy_patient, with a Null value for the field phy_ssn. So When adding a new row, you should try something like this. Insert into table pri_phy_patient values (1234134 ,"Patrick", 32, "331, Patrickson Lane, Patton, CO", 156188)

Comment: 156188 is the value of the field phy_ssn refering the doctor with the ssn 156188

Comment: Do I have to input 'phy_ssn' manually like that? I was hoping, by referencing `doctor(ssn)`, the script would fill in the column automatically.

Comment: Oh no it wouldn’t, that is what I was trying to explain. That is not the job of the Foreign Key to fill the values, it is a way to accept only correct values in this field, referencing existing rows in the referenced table. To automatically fill values after insert, you should read about triggers. Hope this helped!